# Where to place <ul><li> tags correctly as not appearing in view soure

Tags: php, html

With the code below:

```
'<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul>'
```

When I go on the view page source, it highlights in red `</li></ul>`, the reason it does this is because it it not displaying the `<ul><li>` start tags to associate with them. My question is with code above, where am I suppsoe to place the `<ul><li>` tags so that it shows up in view source meaning I know the tags are placed in the correct posistion?

**UPDATE:**

Below is the generated HTML from view source:

```
<td width="11%" class="imagetd">&nbsp;</li></ul></td>
```

Below is the php/html code in full:

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: how exactly does the generated HTML source look?

Comment: Either show the generated HTML or a few more lines above and below from what you've shown so far.

Comment: @user1830984 Yep, found your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your parentheses fall short somewhere, but it's just easier to rewrite it like this; not everything should be a one-liner after all and **especially nested ternary operators**:

```
echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
    echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
    echo htmlspecialchars(is_array($arrImageFile[$key]) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key]);
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
echo '</td>';
```

Comment: I am getting an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'` which is on the `htmlspecialchars....` line

Comment: @user1830984 You're right, sorry about that. Please check again.

Comment: Erm..., There is a big issue now, if I include your code, what happens is that if any rows are empty in the table row, it does not display the table row at all.

Comment: @user1830984 This code doesn't have any rows ... the output starts with `<td>` and ends with `</td>`, that's a column.

Comment: Sorry Jack I meant columns, it is not displaying the column if there is no data in any of the rows under this column. Do you want me to paste the rest of the table code?

Comment: @user1830984 This code will always have something inside the `<td>`, so the problem is not here.